# Keeps printing null

Tags: java, arraylist, null, split

This code is supposed to read one text file of multiple grocery lists and then split them up into an arraylist of separate grocery lists. Then it should split each element of the arraylist (each individual grocery list) into a new arraylist by line. So it's almost like an array list within an arraylist. Does this code work for that? When I try to get the array using the getArray method in my main method and then I print the array but it keeps printing null. What's up?

```
public class Grocery{

    Scanner input;
    String listLine;
    String line;
    ArrayList<String> grocery = new ArrayList<String>();
    String groceryString;
    //ArrayList<String> newString = new ArrayList<String>();
    String store;
    String brand;  
    String serialNumber;
    String[] newString;

    public Grocery()throws IOException{

    File inFile = new File ("groceryList.txt");
    input = new Scanner (inFile);
    String grocery;
    while (input.hasNext())
            {
                    grocery = input.nextLine();
            }
    }

    public void makeLists(){

    while(input.hasNextLine()){
            line = input.nextLine();
                    if(line.equals("<END>")){
                            grocery.add(groceryLine);
                    }
                    else{
                            groceryLine = groceryLine + "\n" + line;
                    }
            }
            }
   public String[] getArray(){

    for(int i=0; i<grocery.size(); i++){
            groceryString = grocery.get(i);
            newString =groceryString.split("\n");
           // store = newString[1];
           // brand = newString[4];
           // serialNumber = newString[5];
            }
    return newString;
    }



}


             ^
```

Comment: Array types don't have an `add()` method.

Comment: Shouldn't it be throwing an exception instead of allowing it to run if the method doesn't exist?

Comment: @Keikoku It shouldn't even get that far; the code shouldn't even *compile*.

Answer (score 0):

`newString` is a `String` array and not an `Arraylist`. It does not contain the `add()` method. You just need to directly assign the resultant `String[]` to it which is returned from the [`String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
newString = emailString.split("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

The add method you are using is a method in the ArrayList class. It doesn't exist in an array.