# Code keeps printing null

Tags: java, arrays, null

This code is supposed to read one text file of multiple grocery lists and then split them up into an arraylist of separate grocery lists. Then it should split each element of the arraylist (each individual grocery list) into a new arraylist by line. So it's almost like an array list within an arraylist. Does this code work for that? When I try to get the array using the getArray method in my main method and then I print the array but it keeps printing null. What's up?

```
public class Grocery {
    Scanner input;
    String groceryLine;
    String line;
    ArrayList<String> grocery = new ArrayList<String>();
    String groceryString;
    //ArrayList<String> newString = new ArrayList<String>();
    String store;
    String brand;  
    String serialNumber;
    String[] newString;

    public Grocery() throws IOException{
        File inFile = new File ("groceryList.txt");
        input = new Scanner (inFile);
        String grocery;
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            grocery = input.nextLine();
        }
    }

    public void makeLists() {
        while(input.hasNextLine()) {
            line = input.nextLine();
            if(line.equals("-finish-")){
                grocery.add(groceryLine);
            } else {
                groceryLine = groceryLine + "\n" + line;
            }
        }
    }

    public String[] getArray() {
        for(int i=0; i<grocery.size(); i++) {
            groceryString = grocery.get(i);
            newString =groceryString.split("\n");
            //store = newString[1];
            //brand = newString[4];
            //serialNumber = newString[5];
        }
        return newString;
    }             
}
```

groceryList.txt looks something like:
-Start-
Store: SuperSupermarket
Address: 23 Rose Road
Brand: Superfoods
Serial Number: 36575
Items:
Bread
Milk
Cheese
Ham
Soup
-finish-(indicates the end of one list)
-start-(start a new list like the first one but different store and stuff)

Comment: paste example format of **groceryList.txt**

Comment: Whats the point of your first while loop?

Comment: Where do you define groceryLine? Your code does not compile when I try it.

Comment: Does this even compile? It looks a bit muddled to me

Comment: `newString = groceryString.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));`

Comment: Sorry I made in mistake in the beginning of the code and declared listLine instead of groceryLine

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keeps printing null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198202/keeps-printing-null)

Answer (score 1):

remove this

```
   String grocery;
        while (input.hasNext())
                {
                        grocery = input.nextLine();
                }
```

and call makeLists at that point.  makeLists will need to take "input" as a parameter too

Comment: How do I put "input" as the parameter?

Comment: ``public void makeLists(Scanner input)`` perhaps?

Comment: Also, why do I have to remove that loop?

Comment: Remove it because it doesn't do anything useful!  It's confused too.  That ``String grocery`` has the same name as the ``ArrayList<String> grocery = new ArrayList<String>();``